# ADFS web authentication loop in IE

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, adfs2.0, adfs, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a mvc4 web app that sits behind ADFS 2.0 authentication, it's configured using the web.config file. The application can be visited by going directly to a URL or as an iframe inside of CRM 2013.

The application works in all (tested) browsers when visiting the URL directly, both redirection to login form and handing the user back to the web app with the proper information in the *ClaimsIdentity*.

However, when visiting the app as an iframe inside CRM2013, internet explorer goes into a continous login loop. You are asked to provide the credentials (which are the same as for logging in to CRM) and when you click ok you get redirected back to the same login page again, to my knowledge the app never receives the hand off.

In Safari, Chrome, Firefox, and Opera the users are able to log into the application inside of CRM as well as outside without any problems (I'd even go as far as saying that it works better than expected for these browsers).

Does anyone have any idea of what I can try or what the problem could be for IE?

**EDIT 1**
I'm thinking it has to do with some security setting and am playing around with the settings in IE. Unchecking this box stops the login form from showing in IE at all and I get an empty page instead.

[image: nothingatall]

Comment: Are all participating sites in the same security zone in IE?

Comment: Yes they are, but it does not seem to matter, same problem in IE10 and IE11. We now have a support ticket with Microsoft. Their initial reaction was: thats weird.

Answer (score 0):

Is the iFrame on the same (sub)domain as the site inside? You can use Fiddler to view your redirect flow, are the cookies added as expected?

I've seen cookies that are overridden by the iFrame host, in that case you lose the auth cookie. Browsers react differently on same domain cookies.

Another problem might be [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options), do you see any warning in the F12 console of IE?